# How do I get iterations of some type into a List while inside a forEach style loop- Dart/Flutter

Tags: list, flutter, iterable, flutter-hive

This is a tough question to articulate, so if I need to elaborate please let me know.

I am using Hive boxes for persistence. This presents a challenge for me. How do I get my users data out of the Hive boxes and into Lists for other tasks and data crunching? I have figured out how to get individual object properties out of the boxes in a way that I can display it all to the user in a DataTable. Now I want to crunch some numbers.

I want to be able to get iterations of data from my loop into a List. This is proving difficult. Example here: I want to get "gross" into a List so I can work with the data.

***Extension I'm using for this***

```
extension ExtendedIterable<E> on Iterable<E> {
  Iterable<T> mapIndex<T>(T f(E e, int i)) {
    var i = 0;
    return this.map((e) => f(e, i++));
  }
  void forEachIndex(void f(E e, int i)) {
    var i = 0;
    this.forEach((e) => f(e, i++));
  }
}
```

***What I'm trying***

```
var box = Hive.box(incomeTable).values.toList();
                    box.forEachIndex(
                      (e, i) {
                        final hiveBox = Hive.box(incomeTable);
                        final incomeData = hiveBox.getAt(i) as Income;
                        final grossData = incomeData.gross;
                        List<double> grossList = [];
                        grossList.add(grossData);       **// This does not work- does not properly add**
                        print(grossData);
                      },
                    );
```

***Current output of grossData above***

```
flutter: 456.0
flutter: 456.0
flutter: 34.0
flutter: 45.0
flutter: 55.0
flutter: 44.0
flutter: 55.0
```

**I can't figure out how to get grossData into my grossList. How can this be done?**

EDIT: As an example in this situation, what I mean by work with the data in a List, in this case I want to sum all the gross income numbers into a total, this can be done many ways but I need all my data in a List.

EDIT: When calling add() and print list i get:

```
flutter: [456.0]
flutter: [456.0]
flutter: [34.0]
flutter: [45.0]
flutter: [55.0]
flutter: [44.0]
flutter: [55.0]
```

And List length remains 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try move the following code outside your for-loop: List grossList = [];

Comment: Thank you. Looks like you forgot to initialize your grossList. Your code should be something like this:

`final grossList = List<double>();`

Comment: Oops, noop mistake. Fixed that, its still not adding to list sequentially as expected. I'm printing the list and I get: `flutter: 456.0
flutter: [456.0]
flutter: [34.0]
flutter: [45.0]
flutter: [55.0]
flutter: [44.0]
flutter: [55.0]` Also i tried printing the list length and I get 1 printed many times.

Comment: Try move the following code outside your for-loop:
`List<double> grossList = [];`